# Sorting Shared Albums with the Apple IOS Photokit

Tags: ios, sorting, photokit

Before I do a lot of fruitless experimenting, does anyone know if you can sort shared albums using the Apple Photokit. I know the native photos app is not able to.

Comment: What are the basis of sorting these albums? The album names?

Comment: All I know is that the built in IOS Photos app enables users to add photos to a shared album but the photos are only displayed in the order they are added to the album.
Now either they can be sorted by creating another app to display them properly, or the shared album is actual like a blog and can't be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i understand from your question, you want to sort based on the timestamp at which asset was added. Try this:

```
_assets = [[NSArray alloc] init];

PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
//Sort according to date
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
//If you want just images
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
//Each album is an assetCollection
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:self.assetsCollection options:options];
_assets = fetchResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by any PHAsset key (mediaType, duration, etc).

```
_assets = [[NSArray alloc] init];
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
//Sort according to date
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"{PHAsset.key}" ascending:NO]];
//For example
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"mediaType" ascending:NO]];
//If you want just images
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
//If you want just videos
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
//If you want both videos and photos
// leave predicate as-is
//Each album is an assetCollection
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:self.assetsCollection options:options];
_assets = fetchResult;
```

So, you can do the same for albums or PHAssetCollections:

```
 let options = PHFetchOptions()
//Sort according to date
options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(@"{PHAssetCollection.key}" ascending:true]
//Query collection with sort descriptor
let result:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.AlbumCloudShared, options: nil)
```